# Paypal in Parse cloud code Authorization error

Tags: ios, json, curl, paypal, parse-platform

In order to confirm payments I need an `access_token`.
I am trying to use a `httpRequest` to get it:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("CheckPayment", function(request, response) {

var basicAuthString = "Basic AXo3jRDk:EEjf1hDMO5t0sKRXqHC62d";

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:"POST",
        url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", 
        headers: {
            "Authorization":basicAuthString,
            "Accept-Language": "en_US",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body:{
            grant_type:"client_credentials"
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error("Request failed with response code " + httpResponse.status);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
    });
});
```

To do the following curl:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "{client-ID}:{secret}" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I get an error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

Can you please help me? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks